# use objects as composite primary key in jpa

Tags: jpa, composite-primary-key

Hello i would like to ask your help concerning **JPA** composite primary key.
For my project i have in my **MySQL database** different tables user, work and participation. For that i have created the class User, Work and Participation as In the table participation i have a composite primary key that refers user primay key and work primary key.
To sum up the following code concern the class **Participation** and **MyKeyParticipation**.

```
@Entity
@ManagedBean
@IdClass(value=MyParticipationKey.class)
public class Participation {
 @Id
 @Column(name="pkIduser")
 private User user;
 @Id
 @Column(name="pkIdet")
 private Work work;
 public User getUser() {
    return user;
 }
 public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
 }
 public Work getWork() {
    return work;
 }
 public void setWork(Work work) {
    this.work = work;
 }}
```

and to finish

```
public class MyParticipationKey implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private User user;
 private Work work;
 public User getUser() {
    return user;
 }
 public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
 }
 public Work getWork() {
    return work;
 }
 public void setWork(Work work) {
    this.work = work;
 }   
}
```

The following lines concern the class User and Work

```
@Entity
@ManagedBean
public class User implements Serializable{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
 private Long pkIduser;
 @NotNull(message="Please enter your firstname")
 @Size(min=3,message="Min size 3 characters!")
 private String firstname;
 @NotNull(message="Please enter your lastname")
 @Size(min=3,message="Min size 3 characters!")
 private String lastname;
 @NotNull(message="Phone number field must not be null")
 @Size(min=5,message="Phone number must have !")
 private String phone;
 private String statut;
 @NotNull(message="Enter valid email")
 @Pattern(regexp="([^.@]+)(\\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\\.)+    ([^.@]+)",message="please enter valid email")
 private String email;
 @NotNull(message="please enter password")
 @Size(min=3,message="Password must have 3 characters")
 private String password;
 public Long getPkIduser() {
    return pkIduser;
 }
 public void setPkIduser(Long pkIduser) {
    this.pkIduser = pkIduser;
 }
 public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
 }
 public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
 }
 public String getEmail() {
    return email;
 }
 public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
 }
 public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
 }
 public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
 }
 public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
 }
 public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
 }
 public String getStatut() {
    return statut;
 }
 public void setStatut(String statut) {
    this.statut = statut;
 }
 public String getPassword() {
    return password;
 }
 public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
 }


}

@Entity
@ManagedBean
public class Work implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
 private Long pkIdet;
 @NotNull(message="Enter the name")
 @Size(min=3,message="Name must have 3 characters!")
 private String name;
 private String type;
 private String description;
 private String statut;
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="pkIduser")
 private User user;

 public User getUser() {
    return user;
 }
 public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
 }
 public String getStatut() {
    return statut;
 }
 public void setStatut(String statut) {
    this.statut = statut;
 }
 public Long getPkIdet() {
    return pkIdet;
 }
 public void setPkIdet(Long pkIdet) {
    this.pkIdet = pkIdet;
 }
 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
 public String getType() {
    return type;
 }
 public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
    return description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
 }
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong here because my IDE Eclipse says to me *that 
The mapping [work] from the embedded ID class [class gct.entities.MyParticipationKey] is an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [myParticipationKey] from the source [class gct.entities.Participation]) can only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.*
*Please help me and any suggestion would be welcome. Thank!*

Comment: And what is wrong? Look at some documentation http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html#a1_1_uni

Comment: @NeilStockton okay i have visited but i don't find what i want. my question concerns two tables joined by the relation N-N which generate a table named "participation".

Comment: that page tells you how to have an Entity as part of the PK, and since you haven't said WHAT you want then how can anyone help?!

Comment: Yes i understand but here i want to know how can i persist composite primary key by objects?

Comment: So put a second Entity as PK, and represent it in the PK class? the same rules apply as that page tells you. You are currently doing it wrong by putting User and Work in the PK class. Read that page and it tells you how to do it

Comment: @NeilStockton this link http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/application_identity.html#primarykey talks about my problem but i don't want to use the  different id i want to replace them by objects. Is it possible ?

Comment: No, that link talks about using BASIC types as @Id fields, and your case is not that, hence why i posted the OTHER link. Where is the code for Work, or User, and what PK do they have?! The PK for those is what you put in your IdClass for Participation, as that links tells you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@IdClass` should contain fields that match the `@Id` fields of the target entities. `MyParticipationKey` should look something like this:

```
public class MyParticipationKey implements Serializable {
    private Long user;
    private Long work;
    ...
}
```

Note that, like a normal `@IdClass`, the field names must match the entity's corresponding field names (`user` and `work`, in this case); but the types of the fields must match the types of the target entities' primary key fields (`Long`, in this case).

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: please can you be explicit?

Comment: If you add the code for `User` and `Work` (and their corresponding `@IdClass`es, if necessary) to your question, I might be able to give you usable `MyParticipationKey ` code.

Comment: I have edited my answer and now you should be able to use its `MyParticipationKey`